# Error When Transferring .XLSB Files Between Computers (Excel Macros)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I recently copied and pasted a few .xlsb personal files from an old computer to a new one (both running Windows 7), but each time I try to open it I get the error:

`"Sorry, we couldn't find C:\PATH\PERSONAL.xlsb. Is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted?"`

Is there something else I need to get from the old computer in order to transfer Excel macros?

Comment: Maybe sir files has reference to a macro in personal.xlsb, try to copy that folks too from your old pc. Or disable macros in excel before opening the file.

Comment: @Mate Where would I find that additional file / reference?

Comment: To find where the Personal.xlsb is (if it exists), you can follow [these instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566). Alternatively, you can type `?Application.StartupPath` in the Immediate Window to find it. (Open the VBEditor with ALT+F11, then press CTRL+G to get the Immediate Window).